# HOMEPATH not set when Jenkins service as as standard user

Tags: jenkins, windows-services, environment-variables, windows-server-2012-r2

This is on Windows 2012 R2 Server and Jenkins 1.609:

I'm running Jenkins as a service, configured to log on as a standard user.  I'm noticing that the environment variables do not contain HOMEDRIVE or HOMEPATH.

When I do 'set' in a build step, I get this output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace E:\jenkins\test\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson5767169902901377197.bat

E:\jenkins\test\workspace>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Roaming
BASE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins
BPADir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\
BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#7
BUILD_ID=7
BUILD_NUMBER=7
BUILD_TAG=jenkins-test-7
BUILD_URL=http://localhost:8080/job/test/7/
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=ARION
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES=1
DXSDK_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2006)\
EXECUTOR_NUMBER=0
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HUDSON_COOKIE=9752005b-45d1-4655-b8c5-4fa37aeedbbc
HUDSON_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins
HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=422669ffa5970bd3
HUDSON_URL=http://localhost:8080/
JENKINS_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins
JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=422669ffa5970bd3
JENKINS_URL=http://localhost:8080/
JOB_NAME=test
JOB_URL=http://localhost:8080/job/test/
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local
NODE_LABELS=master
NODE_NAME=master
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2006)\Utilities\Bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Python33\;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Igence\nims;C:\Program Files (x86)\Aspell\bin;'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe PDF iFilter 11 for 64-bit platforms\bin\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Igence\nims;%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin
PATHEXT=.PY;.SCM;.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=0f06
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SERVICE_ID=jenkins
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp
TFSPowerToolDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\
TMP=C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=ARION
USERNAME=jenkins
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\jenkins
VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
VS110COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\
VS120COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\
VS80COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\
windir=C:\Windows
windows_tracing_flags=3
windows_tracing_logfile=C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log
WINSW_EXECUTABLE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.exe
WORKSPACE=E:\jenkins\test\workspace
```

Is this a consequence of running as a standard user? I thought that would be good practice, since I can then lock down that user?

Actually, my real problem is that I'm then trying to start a git-bash shell and it's not setting HOME properly; hence can't find things like ~/.gitconfig, but I think not having HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH set is the reason why git-bash shell isn't working.

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE: If I explicitly set HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH, I can prove that git-bash now sees a valid $HOME, and paths like ~/.gitconfig work. So why is Windows not setting them in the first place?

Comment: On your Windows machine, the HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH variables are defined as system environment variables ? (and not user environment variables)
If it's system, your Jenkins service should be able to use them.

Comment: It's not a windows issue. Jenkins is not setting local user's variables in a workspace because of "cleaner" builds. Only the global ones.

Answer (score 0):

Verify permissions of subdirectories and files in JENKINS_HOME.
I solved this issue after I updated owner and RW permission of JENKINS_HOME.

Issue on [jenkins-ci](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30291)